# Tv show about another dimension/magic land through a magic mirror

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I keep thinking about a show I used to watch on tv, and damn I wanna know the title :P

It was a live-action show that I saw somewhere between halfway the 90's and halfway the 2000's, and I'm almost sure it was produced around that time as well. It was in English, most likely an American show. It was for kids and/or teenagers.

Although I can hardly remember anything about the story, I do know some of the important details.

---

The show was about a room, I think an attic, where there was a large standing mirror, I think oval of shape. I don't know exactly how, but that mirror somehow connected the normal world (set in the here and now) to another world.

This world 'on the other side of the mirror' had a medieval-based setting, but with some fantasy elements. I remember the classic 'good vs. evil' being the main concept the story was revolved around. Some details and fragments that I rememer:

- One of the 'bad guys' gets a magical or mechanical glove that she can shoot electrical bolts with, making her powerful and feared.
- The intro of the show contains (or perhaps entirely exists of) the magical mirror and a cloudy sky as a background.
- The medieval-like land is what the show is mainly about; the normal world is only seen in a few episodes I think.

Any ideas?

Comment: I seem to have some memory of the same thing. At first I thought it was Mr. Merlin but I don't think so. What I remember also involved a flight of stairs.

Comment: Hey, no it's not Mr. Merlin, it was definately not as old(-looking) as that one. But what do you mean by 'flight of stairs'? Can you give me some more detail about that?

Comment: I picture a mirror at the top of stairs with clouds all around.

Comment: Ah ok, that must be the same show I'm thinking about.

Comment: I know you already know the name of the show you were watching but Once upon a Time on ABC is a really good show :)

Comment: you're not thinking about Alice's Adventures in Wonderland?

Comment: @kat heh no, Dave was right (which is why I accepted his answer ;) ), but thanks

Comment: I'm not sure these are correct. I have memories of this show too. I distinctly remember one snippet of conversation: A guy in Elizabethan dress who appeared from the mirror says "New York? What happened to the old one?"

Comment: Your description sound like what I was thinking, but I thought the mirror was in the girl bedroom and the title had something to do with " Odyssey"

Comment: @Hlumela There seems to be a Canadian children's fantasy tv show called "The Odyssey".. But watching it on Youtube, it doesn't seem like I've ever seen that show myself..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're mixing up two shows. There are 2 Australian shows -

1) [Mirror, Mirror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror,_Mirror_%28TV_series%29)  and 2) [Spellbinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_%28TV_series%29)

Comment: Spellbinder is certainly a good guess ... I remember it being on the Disney Channel in the late 90s...

Comment: Spellbinder's the one, thanks a bunch! You may be right about mixing these two up, because although the youtube videos from Mirror Mirror don't ring any bells, the picture on its wikipedia page is exactly what I pictured for the intro. I'll check them both out :D

Comment: You might have watched Mirror Mirror II, I watched them both as well but Mirror Mirror didn't ring a bell til I saw Mirror Mirror II. It was the graphics of them going through the mirror I remembered

Answer (score 4):

Possible it was [*The 10th Kingdom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_10th_Kingdom), a miniseries with 5 episodes that ran in the year 2000.

Comment: that's what i was thinking as well

Comment: Hey jlmcdonald, thanks for the answer. It's a good guess but unfortunately not the one I'm looking for. The series I'm talking about isn't as 'humoristic' (which I'm getting from watching the trailer of 10th Kingdom) and mostly plays in the fantasy world, rather than our world.

Answer (score 0):

Magic in the Mirror
Magic in the Mirror: Fowl Play

Babes in Toyland

The Hugga Bunch was another mirror movie but has toy munchkins that need hugs to save grandma and only youth know how to hug story line...

The Labyrinth had a flight of stairs in it as well, Sarah was the lead character
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJLnGjhPT1Q